# Spring JPA Transaction issue, not getting saved instance

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm facing issue with sping JPA @Transaction (I think), below is the minimal code:

```
    //package 1
    @Transactional
    public void method_m1(){
        Result result = method_m2();
        audit(result);
    }
    
    //package 2
     @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public Result method_m2(){
    
      Result result = new Result()  
      //creating object say User(User mapped to database table users)
      User u = new User();
      // setting some attributes;
      
      u = userRespositoy.save(user);
      // tried with saveAndFlush no luck
      result.set(u);
      return result ;
    }
    
    //package 3
   @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void audit(Result result){
       CompletableFuture.runAsync(
            () -> {
            //auditing user saving to db
            User user = userRepository.findById(result.get().getId()).orElseThrow(() -> new 
            UserNotFoundException("user not found, userId :" + result.get().getId()));
        });
    }
```

while getting the newly created user by userId from db getting exception.

can anyone please explain what is happening here?

Appreciated in advance.

Comment: To be clear. You don't find the user by id right?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli - yes exactly this problem

Comment: Change REQUIRES_NEW with SUPPORTS. REQUIRES_NEW creates a new DB session, where your DML's in other transactions are not effected yet. And in addition REQUIRES_NEW is one of the biggest  causes of DB deadlocks, so should be used very carefully.

Comment: The problem is that the runAsync runs in another transaaction and doesn't see the created record because the transacation may not be completed. Why do you run it async?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli - I run in async because I don't want response to be delay just because of auditing stuff..

Comment: Ok but why do you call findById. You already have the Result object

Comment: Plus if you don't run it in the same transaction you will not have consistency if one of the two inserts fail